# how to pass slot/data to inertia layout component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

How do I pass a slot or a prop to a `layout` component in inertia?

For example, heres a `ForgotPassword` component:

```
<template>
    <slot name="title">Forgot Password</slot>

    Forgot pw stuff goes here...
</template>

<script>
import CardLayout from "@/Layouts/CardLayout";

export default {
    layout: CardLayout,
}
```

Here is the `CardLayout` component:

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ $slots.title }}</h1>

    <slot/>
</template>
```

Nothing shows up inside the `h1` tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
// CardLayout
<template>
    <h1><slot name="title" /></h1>
    <slot />
</template>

// ForgotPassword
<template>
    <template #title>Forgot Password</template>

    Forgot pw stuff goes here...
</template>
```

Comment: Not working for me. It returns `export 'render' (imported as 'render') was not found`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this here as the solution above does not work. You can pass data to the Layout component by setting a prop value

```
layout: (h, page) => h(Layout, { somePropDataDefinedInLayout: value }, () => page)
```

Comment: This does work for me. I have used page.props.myParameter as value, as I was passing data accepted to the page as prop